# Logical operators and their behavior in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic, operators, logical-operators

Why does this fail?

The way I read this code is "if either a or b or c equals three, then the statement is true". But apparently JavaScript disagrees. Why?

```
function test() {

    var a = 'one';
    var b = 'two';
    var c = 'three';

    return ( ( a || b || c ) === 'three' );

}
```

EDIT:  am aware of the fact that i need to evaluate each expression separately, but was looking for a quicker way to write it. any suggestions will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `( a || b || c )` returns anything that is *truthy* on the first-come-first served basis.
 Here `a` is truthy and hence used. If `a` is *falsey* `b` will be used. If it is *falsey* too, `c` will be used.

So, you always end up comparing `"one" == "three"` since strings are considered *truthy*. You can make use of `Array.some` in this case, which does what you want or how you want it to behave, in your words

> "if either a or b or c equals three, then the statement is true"

```
return [a,b,c].some(function(str){
   return str == "three";
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Your reading of the code is incorrect. Translated to a different form:

```
if (a) {
  return a === "three";
}
if (b) {
  return b === "three";
}
if (c) {
  return c === "three";
}
```

The subexpression `(a || b || c)` returns the first of `a`, `b`, or `c` that is not "falsy". That's `a`, because its value is `"one"`, so that's the overall value that's compared to `"three"`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. this makes sense now. is there anyway to achieve something similar to what I posted? i am aware of the fact that i need to evaluate each expression separately, but was looking for a quicker way to write it. any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: @goodpixels well there's not really a way to do that that's not somewhat clumsy. You have to do an explicit comparison to each one. I guess you could wrap them in an array and then use `.indexOf()` but that seems clumsy and less obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This evaluates to is a, b, or c (which will be true or false) the string-equivalent of "three". Which will always be false.
In order to achieve what you want, you need

```
return (a === 'three') || (b === 'three') || (c === 'three');
```